# Why am I getting undefined with i18next handlebars

Tags: handlebars.js, i18next, express-handlebars, next-i18next

I am getting an undefined variable name using i18next with handlebars

Following is my code to init i18next [with this package](https://github.com/Aller-Couleur/handlebars-i18n):

```
const i18next = require('i18next');
const HandlebarsI18n = require("handlebars-i18n");
import resources from "./i18n/messages";

i18next.init({
    resources,
    debug: true,
    fallbackLng: "en",
    lng : "en"
});

HandlebarsI18n.init();

export default i18next;
```

In my index.ts where I have the handlebars compiled I have
`import "./i18n"`

Where I use the i18next looks like this:

```
<span class="typography-h3">{{__ getNodeLabel .}}{{#if attributes.required}}
   <span class="required-indicator">*</span>{{/if}}
</span>
```

If I replace the `{{__ getNodeLabel .}}` with something like `{{__ "Password"}}` I still get undefined not to sure what is up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the issue has to do with the `i18next` peerDependency defined in the package.json of the [handlebars-i18n](https://github.com/Aller-Couleur/handlebars-i18n/blob/master/package.json#L39) package. In the latest version of handlebars-i18n, the `i18next` peerDependency version is `^21.6.14`.

Assuming you have recently installed `i18next` into your own project with the command `npm install i18next`, you will have a dependency in your project's package.json for `i18next` with the latest version which is currently `^21.9.2`.

I am not an expert on how npm handles peerDependencies, but it seems that due to the differences between these two versions, `^21.6.14` and `^21.9.2`, that npm is installing both.

This means that in your project's `node_modules` folder there are two versions of `i18next` - one at the top-level of your `node_modules` (`21.9.2`) and one at `node_modules/handlebars-i18n/node_modules` (`21.6.14`).

Its the two versions that cause the problem. When you initialize `i18next` by calling `i18next` in your code, you are initializing the `21.9.2` version. But `handlebars-i18n` loads the `21.6.14` version and it *never gets initialized* and all calls to its translate, `.t`, method return `undefined`.

I was able to get this working by uninstalling `i18next` and then installing it again using the same version that is defined in the `handlebars-i18n` package.json:

```
npm uninstall i18next
npm install i18next@21.6.14
```

This ensures that only one `i18next` is installed.